# Using Smart Pointers

Tags: c++, c++11

I am working on a legacy C++ app which has the following function,

```
char* CreateNewString (const char* node)
{
   int len = (int) strlen(node) + 1;
   char * ptr = new char [len];
   strcpy_s(ptr, len, node);
   return ptr;
}
```

This function is called from many classes in the app and here's an example use case.

```
char * nodeID = obj.CreateNewString(process->GetNodeID());
```

The app calls a different process and get a node ID as char pointer and then passes it to **CreateNewString** function to dynamically allocate memory for a new string.

Nowhere in the app after the above call, it's deleting the memory. From what I observe, there's a definite memory leak here.

I think there're few ways of resolving this issue. But I want to explore using the smart pointers in C++11 first before trying anything else.

**What I Tried:**

So I came up with following function:

```
  char* CreateNewString (const char* node) 
  {
       int len = (int) strlen(node) + 1;
       shared_ptr<char> ptr (new char [len](), [](char* p) {delete [] p;});
       strcpy_s(ptr.get(), len, node);
       return ptr.get();
    }
```

The goal is to keep function signature the same, i.e. it returns a char pointer, so that I don't have to make changes at all calling places.

The above is not working as **ptr** is released as it's declared inside the scope of this function.

My goal is to:

1. Use C++ 11 smart pointers to achieve this with minimum code changes to the existing application.

An alternative way I am aware of is to dynamically initialize array in calling places itself and then delete it before end of that scope. But I want to explore new C++ features before going back to traditional C++ way. BTW, I am not interested in exploring `std::string` at this point.

Comment: Instead of a smart pointer, can I interest you in a [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)?

Comment: Not interested in std::string for now. My intention is also to learn how to use new C++ 11, 14 & 17 features in an efficient way to fix these kind of issues. Agreed, it's memory leak,

Comment: Avoiding the correct tool for the job just to use "new features" is going backwards.

Comment: You will have refactoring to do to handle the smart pointers anyway, so do the right thing, use a string.

Comment: @donguy76 At first try to update such bad statements like this in your code. int len = (int) strlen(node) + 1; Secondly it is not enough information about how the pointers are used.

Comment: The C++11 "smart pointers" aren't really pointers, they are more like objects with special ownership semantics. They are of no use in this situation, and trying to "retrofit" them into existing code is often futile.

Comment: @donguy76: _"Not interested in std::string for now. My intention is also to learn how to use new C++ 11, 14 & 17 features in an efficient way to fix these kind of issues."_ - you _really_ should watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YnWhqhNdYyk).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see a way you can have the function return char pointer and still use smart pointers. There could be potential hacks on getting it done, but all of them have overheads and more importantly, unnecessary code. My suggestion is for a simple change on the new function you wrote and then do another even more simpler change at all calling places.

So the function will look like this,

```
 shared_ptr<char> CreateNewString (const char* node) 
  {
       int len = (int) strlen(node) + 1;
       shared_ptr<char> ptr (new char [len](), [](char* p) {delete [] p;});
       strcpy_s(ptr.get(), len, node);
       return ptr;
  }
```

And then anywhere it get's called, simply add a **.get()**

```
char * nodeID = obj.CreateNewString(process->GetNodeID()).get();
```

Answer (score 6):

You could:

- return the `shared_ptr`
- return a `std::string`
- leave everything as it is

Those are your options.

Comment: Or quit and go for an apple instead.

Comment: Yeah or that I suppose

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of a hack, but it will work and you will not have a memory leak.  What you can do is add a static vector of smart pointers  and then when you call the function you store the pointer in the vector so that it won't go out of scope at the end of the function.  That would look like

```
char* CreateNewString (const char* node) 
{
    std::size_t len = strlen(node) + 1;
    static std::vector<std::unique_ptr<char[]>> data_pool; // static pool, destroyed at end of program
    data_pool.push_back(std::unique_ptr<char[]>(new char [len]{})); // add pointer to pool
    strcpy_s(data_pool.back().get(), len, node); // copy the string
    return data_pool.back().get(); // return pointer to the managed data
}
```

using a `std::unique_ptr`, which deletes arrays correctly so we don't need a custom deleter

Do note that using this solution you wont have a memory leak, but all of the allocated memory will last until the end of the program.  You don't gain anything, but at least you are guaranteed the memory is deallocated before the program terminates.

Comment: This ... seems quite dangerous to suggest to be honest. I consider it a sort of memory leak since there's no way to return things to the pool (i.e. delete them before program end). Still, creds for the inventive literal answer to the OP's question!

Comment: @Jarod42 Yep.  I was thinking `string` worked like `vector` but forgot it can't because SSO is allowed.  I'll remove it for now until I can think of a way make it work.

Comment: Since unreleased heap gets released when a process terminates, I don't see any functional difference. It really needs a major refactoring which is not what the OP wants.

Comment: @doug It does offer 1 benefit in this case, profiles wont yell at you for leaking memory.  If the OP was dealing with objects that have destructors with side effects, then this also stops the UB you'd have for not calling those destructors.

Comment: Good point. It will shut up profilers that check for memory leaks and it could be a benefit if the OP has other complex objects that that acquire resources that need to be released on exit. But the main issue with memory leaks are programs that leak and keep allocating new heap chunks. He may or may not have an issue with that but if he does, dealing with it will require significant refactoring.